# data re-coding in csv file

Tags: r, csv

I'm new in using R. Actually it would be great if I can have code for the following problem.
I have a large no. of variable but I'm just presenting for few. suppose I have a csv file named "A" of the following form:

```
  s    e     d   v1    v2    v3    v4   v5    v6
  2    6     2    1
  3    5     4    1    1                       1
                  1    1     1     1           1
  2    3     5    1                1     1     1
```

In the above data file blank spaces means missing values.Now I want to put 5 in the variables starting from s=2 and ending at e=6, e.i. starting from v2 to v6, if the variable d is greater than 1. But I want the columns s & e as the index of starting and ending of entry, I don't want the incorporation of any numeric value directly, so that I can use this program for a very large number of variables and cases, and for that the entry of 5 in the data file depends on the s and e variables. e.g. If s is 2 then the recoding should start from v2 and if e is 6 the recoding should end at v6. Now I want my new table looks like as follows:

```
  s    e     d   v1    v2    v3    v4   v5    v6
  2    6     2   1     5     5     5    5      5
  3    5     0   1     1                       1
                 1     1     1     1           1
  2    3     5   1     5     5     1    1      1
```

It after such re-coding, I want to write the whole file in the same CSV file that was named 'A'. It would be great if u can solve this problem.

Comment: What is the role of the row with blank s, e and d values?

Comment: In the first table, the value of row 2-column 3 (4) is wrong?

Comment: @euanM the row with blank s, e, d, probably means that he wants to leave that row as it is.

Comment: yep, Teja, u r right.....PereG: actually the value u have detected is just a condition, I have made mistake but that should not be a problem....thanks a lot....

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't provide a reproducible example of your real data, my answer is going to be a tentative one. Probably you don't have sole those columns and names, so take this as an starting point. There might be also a more efficient manner (less key stroke) of achieving what you want, this is just one way. 
I'm using the `mutate` function from `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
A = read.table(text ="s,e,d,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6
2,6,2,1,,,,,
3,5,4,1,1,,,,1
3,5,0,1,1,,,,1
,,,1,1,1,1,,1
2,3,5,1,,,1,1,1", sep=",", header=TRUE)

> A
   s  e  d v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
1  2  6  2  1 NA NA NA NA NA
2  3  5  4  1  1 NA NA NA  1
3  3  5  0  1  1 NA NA NA  1
4 NA NA NA  1  1  1  1 NA  1
5  2  3  5  1 NA NA  1  1  1

B <- mutate(A, v1 = ifelse(d>1 & is.na(v1), 5, v1),
                v2 = ifelse(d>1 & is.na(v2), 5, v2),
                 v3 = ifelse(d>1 & is.na(v3), 5, v3),
                 v4 = ifelse(d>1 & is.na(v4), 5, v4),
                 v5 = ifelse(d>1 & is.na(v5), 5, v5),
                 v6 = ifelse(d>1 & is.na(v6), 5, v6))

> B
   s  e  d v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
1  2  6  2  1  5  5  5  5  5
2  3  5  4  1  1  5  5  5  1
3  3  5  0  1  1 NA NA NA  1
4 NA NA NA  1  1  1  1 NA  1
5  2  3  5  1  5  5  1  1  1
```

Once done with correcting data, just write the CSV file:

```
write.csv(B, file="outfile.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Or just `mutate_each_(A, funs(ifelse(d > 1 & is.na(.), 5, .)), names(A)[-(1:4)])`

Comment: @PierreLafortune That rocks.

Comment: thanks a lot, finally I have been able to run the command.....thank you very much.....

Answer (score 0):

The solution be Daniel works but here's another one you might find easier since you're new to R and won't have used `dplyr` before.

```
so <- read.csv("so.txt")

for(row in 1:nrow(so)) {
  if(so[row,"d"]>1 && !is.na(so[row,"s"]) && !is.na(so[row,"e"])) {
     so[row,seq(so[row,"s"],so[row,"e"])+3] <- 5
  }
}

write.csv(so, "so_new.txt")
```

where the file `so.txt` contains

```
s,e,d,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6
2,6,2,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
3,5,0,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1
NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,NA,1
2,3,5,1,NA,NA,1,1,1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, finally I have been able to run the command.....thank you very much.....